# python how do use filter and diff in a row?

Tags: python, pandas

so basically in i need to remove objects in the dataframe who's column `transaction_date` (row containing datetime objects) doesnt streak by month (basically they need to have a consistent `transaction_date` row based on the month, so if one month is skipped inside the `transaction_date` row they're filtered out)

currently this is the code i've come up with

```
seconds_per_month = 2629746
sorted_df = dataframe.sort_values(by=["transaction_date"])
engaged_transactions = sorted_df.groupby(["username"]).filter(lambda x: (x["transaction_date"].diff().dt.total_seconds() <= seconds_per_month).all())
```

im trying to filter out users where one of their `transaction_date` row skipped a month however `engaged_transactions` becomes empty

how do i achieve this?

Comment: How did you arrive at 2629746 being the number of seconds in a month? I don't think it's a good idea to look at seconds here (months can have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days, and let's not forget leap seconds and all sorts of other issues). Wouldn't it make more sense to look at the dates systematically and filter out the months directly?

Comment: @TimPietzcker my problem is the `TimedeltaProperties` object doesnt contain information about months when i do `x["transaction_date"].diff().dt` to get the difference between months sequentially

Comment: OK, what happens when you set `seconds_per_month = 2419200` (which is the number of seconds in a 28-day-month)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker nothing, still empty

Comment: OK, so the approach itself is not working. Sorry, I don't know enough about pandas to see what the underlying problem is. It might help it you could offer some sample data to make the problem reproducible.